# Definition of a complex prime

Tags: prime-numbers, complex-numbers

If there would be such a thing as a complex prime number,
how would it be defined?

A normal prime is defined as a number only dividable by one or itself..
would that be "1+1i" with complex numbers?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer |
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element

Comment: @anon: You should post your link as an answer. The web page answers the question clearly and thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, had you posted it as an answer, I would have accepted it because it helped me a great deal ;)